# Ruby naming conventions?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

For instance, for constants, is it:

`THIS_CONSTANT`

`This_Constant`

`ThisConstant`

Or something else...?

In fact, is there any sort of (quasi|)official reference for this whole subject?

I'd also like to be able to quickly double check questions like:

- What naming patterns are enforced by Ruby itself (eg, `Constant`s *must* start with a capital, right?) and which are simply conventions (`method_name`s should be in snake case, right?)?
- Are there any conventions for how to write a reminder of what class a variable is supposed to be into its name? ("Hungarian notation" or whatever... I mean, I kinda got the impression that if you ever feel the need to use it in Ruby code, you're Doing It Wrong, but regardless, *is* there a convention?)

and so on...

Comment: Hungarian notation isn't used in Ruby. Partly that's because trying to  describe the type of a variable in its name results in unwieldy names that are often lacking a good description of what they really are, and, because in Ruby we are supposed to use duck-typing, meaning that the variable type is often less important than what it can act like. If it can convert itself, or be easily converted, what difference does it matter what type it is. Hungarian-notation is more important when it's difficult to convert from one type to another.

Comment: Make yourself and your team a favour and install `Rubocop` in all of your projects. Nobody should be loosing time talking about conventions.

Comment: @Daniel: if someone wants to implement and enforce a certain way of working, one must talk about conventions. Rubocop enforces a certain convention therefore people need to talk about it.

Answer (score 78):

[The Ruby Style Guide](https://rubystyle.guide/) is a public effort to recommend consistent conventions and best practices to Ruby developers. You should check it out.

Answer (score 16):

In brief

The camel case for classes and modules definition we use `CamelCase`

The snake case for files, variables and methods: `snake_case`

Comment: usually I see that referred to as `TitleCase` to differentiate it from `camelCase`

Comment: I believe the technical term is Pascal Case.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting in your text editor can give you some good clues as you're learning a language and trying to develop an instinct for its conventions, enforced and otherwise. I use the Linux Gedit editor.

Yesterday I was pleasantly surprised to find that some of the conventions for commenting recommended by The Ruby Style Guide https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide, such as `# TODO` and `# FIXME`, show up as bold face bright yellow. Constant names with ALL CAPS are bold cyan. Of course, different editors use different color schemes.